# Jquery converting &quot; to literal quotation

Tags: jquery, dom, html-parsing, double-quotes, quote

I am seeing some unexpected behavior in Jquery. It appears jquery is converting `&quot;` to literal double quotes, which is messing with form validation in a single page app I am working on. The content is set via jquery at which point the the form fields containing `&quot;` get converted to `"` which breaks the form.

As a test, I tried regular JS dom manipulation and got different results. This appears to be consistant amont 1.x and 2.x versions of Jquery.

Here is the code I tried:

```
// Regular Javascript
var e = document.createElement('div');
var textNode=document.createTextNode('&amp;');
e.appendChild(textNode)
console.log(e.childNodes) //=> ['&amp;']

var e = document.createElement('div');
var textNode=document.createTextNode('&quot;');
e.appendChild(textNode)
console.log(e.childNodes) //=> ['&quot;']

// vs. Jquery

e = $('<div>')
content = '&amp;'
e.html(content)
console.log(e.html()) //=> &amp;

e = $('<div>')
content = '&quot;'
e.html(content)
console.log(e.html()) // => " (a quote)
```

Any thoughts?

**Edit**
Jquery doc says .html() is based on the browsers innerHTML implementation. 
However, using the pure JS code from above:
console.log(e.innerHTML)  yeilds: &amp; and &quot; respectively.

Additionally, calling innerHTML on the actual dom stored in jquery yeilds:
console.log(e.get(0).innerHTML) & and " respectively.

```
e = $('<div />');
content = '&quot;'
e.html(content)
console.log(e.get(0).innerHTML) // => "
console.log(e.html()) // => "
console.log(e.text()) // => "

e = $('<div />');
content = '&amp;'
e.html(content)
console.log(e.get(0).innerHTML) //=> &amp;
console.log(e.html()) //=> &amp;
console.log(e.text()) //=> &
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery for this. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is superior in every way.

Answer (score 4):

The [$.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method will decode / encode HTML entities. To bypass this behavior consider using [$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead:

```
var e = $("<div>"), content = "&quot;";
e.text(content);
console.log(e.text()); // outputs &quot;
```

**EDIT**

You may consider just using a regex replace to find the offending quotes and encode them yourself like so:

```
var e = $("<div>"), content = "&quot;&amp;";
e.html(content);
console.log(e.html()); // outputs "&amp;

var e_encoded = e.html().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
console.log(e_encoded); // outputs &quot;&amp;
```

Keep in mind that the above will also encode any quotes used for HTML attributes within any tags contained in the `content` variable, which is persumably why the `$.html()` method does not encode them to begin with.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It only appears to do that for double quote though. re: &amp; is left alone. And there is surrounding markup so I am unable to use .text(). This is s distilled down example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) rather than `.html()`.

Comment: It only appears to do that for double quote though. re: &amp; is left alone.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is that this is expected behavior because jquery is just wrapping the browser's innerHTML method.

This is sad news it seems for single page apps that need to differentiate between " and " in rendered form input etc.